# Getting error while comparing the list with another list

Tags: python

New to python and pls correct me if i was wrong.
Getting the error for the below code :

```
import string
test1=list(string.ascii_lowercase)
test2=list(string.ascii_uppercase)
test4= list(input("enter the string: "))
if test4 in test1:
     print("TRUE")
else:
     print("FALSE")
```

getting always `false` for the lower case input names/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enter `anything` here, then `test4 = "anything"`. `if test4 in test1` will check to see if `anything` is a subsequence of `string.ascii_lowercase` (which it is not).

If you happen to enter any consecutive letters, it should work fine (`test4 = "bcdef"` or etc)

Comment: can u suggest me how to check  if i enter any name or string as input and it will say true if the string contains all lowercase letters

Comment: Check out `str.islower`.